# Python get request only downloading HTML no the file

Tags: python, download, get, request

i've tried a bunch of different ways, all with the same result.

It just downloads the html from the login page. So i'm pretty sure the authentication isn't happening. Any ideas?

```
      import requests

userid = '???????'
password = '??????'


site_url = 'https://www.pencarrie.com/marketing/website-options/data/enhanced-data'
file_url = 'https://www.pencarrie.com/export/products.zip'


o_file = 'products.zip'  

# create session
s = requests.Session()
# GET request. This will generate cookie for you
s.get(site_url)
# login to site.
s.post(site_url, data={'_username': userid, '_password': password})
# Next thing will be to visit URL for file you would like to download.
r = s.get(file_url)

# Download file
with open(o_file, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(r.content)
print(f"requests:: File {o_file} downloaded successfully!")

# Close session once all work done
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

userid = '???????'
password = '??????'


site_url = 'https://www.pencarrie.com/marketing/website-options/data/enhanced-data'
file_url = 'https://www.pencarrie.com/export/products.zip'


o_file = 'products.zip'  

# create session
s = requests.Session()
# GET request. This will generate cookie for you
s.get(site_url)
# login to site.
s.post(site_url, data={'_username': userid, '_password': password})
# download file
r = s.get(file_url, stream=True)
with open(o_file, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but No sorry, exactly the same.